# When I use QGIS with OpenLayers Plugin,

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

When I use Open Street Map and execute it as a background, it couldn't show up. Instead, The screen in QGIS became black.

How can I reorder it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @JumpeiTakubo! Make sure the project CRS is set to `EPSG:3857`. In the _Layer Order Panel_ (which you can enable from the menubar : `View > Panels > Layer Order Panel), change the order where any layer above another will be shown on top. Also, you may want to consider using **QuickMapServices** which has more layers available and is updated more frequently :)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Sorry for late response, and thank you I can check what I failed by your advice. :)